# How to add class dynamically inside a loop using asp

Tags: asp-classic, masonry

I want to add a class for Masonry in the loop while.

What can I do for loop should be only one?

Is output to the three data three times.

Is there another way?

```
<div id="box-container">
<div class="grid-sizer"><!-- avl for packery to get grid size --></div>
<%
'creates an array
Dim x, y, z
x = Array("w2 h1", "w1 h2", "w1 h1")

  rso()
  cate = "fo01"
  SQL = " SELECT  TOP 3 * FROM ms_dbtable WHERE category = '"& cate &"' ORDER BY sort_idx ASC "
  rs.open SQL, dbcon, 3
  If Not rs.eof Then
  While Not rs.EOF
  For Each y In x
%>
<div class='box snip1328 <%=y%>'>
    <%        If rs("thumb") = "" Then %>
    <img src="/img/tlogo.gif"></a>
    <%        Else %>
    <img src="/data/fo01/<%=rs("thumb")%>"></a>
    <%        End If %>
</div>
<%
Next
%>

<%
rs.MoveNext
Wend
End If
rsc()
%>
```

```
<style>
.w1 {width: 138px;}
.h1 {height: 138px;}
.w2 {width: 280px;}
.h2 {height: 280px;}
.w3 {width: 422px;}
.h3 {height: 422px;}
</style>
```

The result is output as a duplicate image.

The output data has Blurring the face picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBIC7.png)

Comment: This code is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Why do you know why?

Comment: Because of this `'"& cate &"'` but only if the `cate` variable is set dynamically through a `Request()` variable. At the moment the value is hard coded so it's safe enough, although I wouldn't get too comfortable with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are selecting TOP 3, and there are three elements in the array,
you could move the array index within the loop using a counter.

```
If Not rs.eof Then
  Dim xindex : xindex=0
  While Not rs.EOF

%>
<div class='box snip1328 <%=x(xindex)%>'>
    <%        If rs("thumb") = "" Then %>
    <img src="/img/tlogo.gif"></a>
    <%        Else %>
    <img src="/data/fo01/<%=rs("thumb")%>"></a>
    <%        End If %>
</div>
<%
    xindex = xindex + 1
    rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
```